# How to registr Automapper configuration class in global.asax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper, global-asax

I dont want to configure Automapper in global.asax. Instead of I want to create class that implemets Profile interface and registr this class in global.asax. But I dont know how to registr class in global.asax by it's direction. How can I do?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 6):

You can register the configuration as below.

**Profile class**

```
 public class UserProfile : Profile
    {
        public UserProfile()
        {
            this.CreateMap<UserDTO, User>();
            this.CreateMap<User, UserDTO>().ForMember(dest => dest.Company, opt => opt.Ignore()); ;
        }
    }
```

**AutoMap class**

```
public static class AutoMap
    {
        public static IMapper Mapper { get; set; }

        public static void RegisterMappings()
        {
            var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(
               config =>
               {
                   config.AddProfile<UserProfile>();
               });

            Mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
        }
    }
```

**Global.asax**

```
AutoMap.RegisterMappings();
```

Comment: Divyang Patel, I did all of theese and when I call Mapper UsersModelDTO userDto = Mapper.Map<User, UsersModelDTO>(user); then I got this  error: Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods

Comment: Solved, All I need to change in  constructor of UserProfile is using  Mapper.Initialize like this  public UserProfile()
        { Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
            cfg .CreateMap<UserDTO, User>();
            cfg .CreateMap<User, UserDTO>().ForMember(dest => dest.Company, opt => opt.Ignore()); ;
        }}

Comment: You can use like this. `var userDTO = AutoMap.Mapper.Map<UserDTO>(user);`

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried (RTFM) reading the manual? [Documentation](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html)